# Bluez, multiple GATT servers running on the same computer

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bluetooth, bluez

In other socket applications you can’t open a port that is already in use but bluetoothd seems to accept several listening GATT servers running in parallel, how is that possible?

I try to setup a GATT server using bluez 5.35 on Raspberry Pi Jessie. I have made an application that starts the GATT server much like the example btgatt-server.c using l2cap socket. I have a custom characteristic that a client application can connect and use. I have also setup to enable advertising using hci commands (it is set to enable just after listen() command on the socket).
I have done so the application auto start in rc.local. My problem is that after reboot, sometimes I don't see my own characteristics but I get a complete other list of services/characteristics. If I don’t start my own application and only enable advertising (*sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv*) I see the same list so it seems to be running a GATT server by default.

What mechanism in bluez decide if my services/characteristics or the other ones (I guess loaded by default plugins) are visible? They are never combined and visible at the same time and I don’t see any error messages during my application startup even if I can’t see the characteristics from the client and don’t get anything by accept(). How can I be sure my characteristics is always visible?